# how do I make a vertical going-down cover segue in xcode?

Tags: xcode, segue

the default modal segue cover vertical only has going-up effect only. how do I make one that is going down?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode custom segue - Opposite of Cover Vertical (top to bottom) - COMPLETE NEWBIE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081880/xcode-custom-segue-opposite-of-cover-vertical-top-to-bottom-complete-newbi)