# How to present a modal view coming from the top?

Tags: ios, swift

I have few modal view. Everytime when I call them through a segue, they appear coming from the bottom. Is there a way to choose from which direction the modal view comes? Like from the right? the left?...

Comment: Have you tried to search here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081880/xcode-custom-segue-opposite-of-cover-vertical-top-to-bottom-complete-newbi - somethink like this

Comment: Thanks for the link. I actually didn't look for anything related to Objective-C as I learned only Swift but it's actually understandable.

Comment: To learn swift you should know Obj-C also. Apple didn't cancel Obj-C and it's working together

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by defining your own custom transitions. Checkout the WWDC2013 session: [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/#218)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree, but as this is a very general question, I decided to post a short answer with an inspiration and to provide a link with more details. But I this is not just a link-only answer. I'm sure that simply googling "Custom Transition iOS", provides plenty of information. I think this is sufficient for this type of question.

Comment: Does this answer the question? If not (and it clearly does not), then it's a link-only answer and should be posted as a comment instead.

Comment: Alright, but what kind of answer do you expect for a general question like this? I provided the name of the technique and the name of the reference including link. So in my opinion the question is answered. It's not that I just posted an uncommented link is it?

Comment: I'll note the link is password-protected & requires the user to sign up for a developer account (admittedly a free account). @croX part of the problem here is that the question itself not a good fit for this site to begin with because it's pretty broad. Would it be possible to add an example of a modal view with a custom transition, even as pseudo-code?

Comment: Well in my case I actually didn't know the name of the technique indeed. It might be obvious for many, but I didn't think as "transition" as the word to explain what I wanted to do. So for that thanks, and google will do the reste.

Comment: Me thinks: broad question, broad answer. The link seems to be useful as someone already voted it up.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)